# What is the difference between parfois & quelquefois?

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire

What is the difference between parfois & quelquefois?  They both mean sometimes, but is one more formal?

Answer (score 3):

"Quelquefois" is less frequent than "parfois" and the difference between the two can be likened to the difference between "at times" and "sometimes," respectively.

Comment: [Usage frequency](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?year_start=1800&year_end=2019&content=parfois%2Cquelquefois&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cparfois%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cquelquefois%3B%2Cc0#)

Comment: Thank you, great answer!

Comment: if you agree with my answer, could you mark it as the correct answer, please? thanks!!